# Debugger icon for vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I been seeing this debug icon ever since I started using VSCode and I can't seem to find it. Can anyone help me find an answer? I checked tags that had product icons in them, but no luck. I thought the icon looked good! Thanks!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ao9xf.png)

Comment: it is the previous version of the debug icon used, if you want to get it browse the repo for updates to the icon and copy an old version to your install

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you properly configured the launch.json file then launch the debug:  (F5) or Run->Start debugging.

Comment: why is this an answer for the debug icon